# Marshmallow not giving errors

Tags: python, schema, marshmallow

If I used Marshmallow to create a schema like this:

```
class TempSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Int()
    email = fields.Str(required=True,
                   validate=validate.Email(error='Not a valid email address'))
    password = fields.Str(required=True,
                      validate=[validate.Length(min=6, max=36)],
                      load_only=True)
```

and then I do something like:

```
temp = TempSchema()
temp.dumps({'email':123})
```

I'd expect an error but I get:

```
MarshalResult(data='{"email": "123"}', errors={})
```

Why isn't this or anything else showing up as an error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Validation only happens on deserialization (using `Schema.load`), not serialization (`Schema.dump`).

```
data, errors = schema.load({'email': '123'})
print(errors)
# {'email': ['Not a valid email address'], 'password': ['Missing data for required field.']}
```

If you don't need the deserialized data, you can use `Schema.validate`.

```
errors = schema.validate({'email': '123'})
print(errors)
# {'email': ['Not a valid email address'], 'password': ['Missing data for required field.']}
```